# $\operatorname{P}$ vs. $P$ in probability

Tags: probability, notation, random-variables

Below are three separate notations my textbook uses:

> $\operatorname{P}(X)$: the probability that an **event** $X$, which is a **subset** of the sample space, occurs
>
> $\operatorname{P}(X=x)$: the probability the **random variable** $X$ assumes the specific **numerical value** $x$
>
> $P(x)$: probability distribution **function**, where $P(x)=\operatorname{P}(X=x)$

I understand that it’s generally claimed that upright font is meant to indicate operators while slanted or italicizes font is meant to indicate variables and functions, but in reality, the conventions are [much more nuanced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163111/107979) than that.

### So, why the care to distinguish $\operatorname{P}$ from $P$? How important is it to do so?

Is this simply a regional convention? I have noticed that Europeans use upright symbols more than do Americans (e.g., $\mathrm{d}x$ vs. $dx$), which could account for what I’m seeing.

If you’re curious, my textbook is [*Mathematics for the International Student: Mathematics HL (Core) third edition*](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9781921972119) by Haese et al. and is Australian in origin.

Comment: Different things deserve different notations. The first two is a measure applied to events, while the last one is simply a function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first two examples of notation are really the same, since $\{X=x\}$ is an event. It makes sense that your text takes care to distinguish the probability function $\operatorname{P}(\cdot)$ from the distribution function $P(\cdot)$, since the former operates on sets (events) while the latter operates on real numbers (elements of the sample space). In most treatments of probability that I've encountered, the ambiguity is avoided by having the symbol $P$ (in whatever font or face) reserved just for the probability function, while some other notation ($f$ or $f_X$ or $p$, etc) is used for the distribution function.

Comment: Sorry to do this, but I just updated the question itself: “So, why the care to distinguish $\operatorname{P}$ from $P$? How important is it to do so?” Would you care to add more?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor As others have commented, the two entities are distinct so they deserve different notation. It's not strictly necessary, since a close reading will make the distinction clear (by checking whether the argument is a set vs a real number). However, the authors of the text were apparently unwilling to have readers endure what is often called "an abuse of notation", hence the two versions $\operatorname{P}$ and $P$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathsf P(\,\cdot\,)$ is generally used to indicate the probability function over sets of outcomes (aka events) in a probability space, usually denoted as $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathsf P)$ or such.  (Where $\Omega$ denotes the sample space, and $\mathcal F$ denotes the sigma-algebra.)  As such, $\mathsf P(X=x)$ is the probability for the event where random variable $X=x$, and $\mathsf P(X\leq x)$ is the probability for the event where $X$ is at most $x$, and so forth.

$$\mathsf P:\Omega\mapsto [0;1]$$

$P(\,\cdot\,)$, or more often $P_X(\,\cdot\,)$ or $p_{\small\lower{0.25ex} X}(\,\cdot\,)$, is typically used to indicate the probability mass function over values of a discrete random variable.   So thus $P(x)$ is the probability mass for the random variable having value $x$.
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad{ P:\Bbb R\mapsto[0;1]\\(\text{for real-valued discrete random variable, }X)}$$

In short: $P(x)=\mathsf P(X{=}x)$.

How important is it to make the visual distinction between the two functions?   Well, they *are* different things, so to be properly rigorous , a distinction *should* be made.   And although it does not necessarily have to be made by *the font*, it is convenient to follow the convention.

$\tiny\text{But it is not like the secret maths police will sent out assassins if you forget.}$

Comment: Love the quip at the end ;)